# Updating a Pandas dataframe by replacing NaN values in a column with not NaN values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'd need to update an original dataframe in case there is a match between an object having NaN value but that has a match when it is within Field with another object.

Giving you an example:

Original df:

```
Object Field (other columns)
house  Christmas 
table  house
tablet nan
Christmas  nan
chair  table
oven   nan
house  bottle
bottle nan
```

I'd have at the end a table which looks as follows

df1

```
Object Field (other columns)
house  Christmas 
table  house
Christmas  house
chair  table
oven   nan
house  bottle
bottle house
```

For updating the original dataframe, I guess that I'd check each object where there is a NaN value in the Field column and, for each of them, check if it has an Object correspondence when it is in the Field column.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping from `Field` and `Object` columns of `df`.  Then, use that mapping on `NaN` entries of `Field` to get the corresponding `Object` values in other rows to fill-up the NaN values, as follow:

```
mapping = df.loc[df['Field'].notna()].set_index('Field')['Object']
mapping = mapping.groupby(level=0).first()    # Use the first entry if more than one

df1 = df.copy()
df1.loc[df1['Field'].isna(), 'Field'] = df1['Object'].map(mapping)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

      Object      Field
0      house  Christmas
1      table      house
2     tablet        NaN
3  Christmas      house
4      chair      table
5       oven        NaN
6      house     bottle
7     bottle      house
```

Comment: Thanks SeaBean. The last line (df1.loc ...) returns this error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. Do you know what could cause it?

Comment: @LdM  This should normally indicate some duplicate entries in index.  Anyway, I tested your sample data and got no error.  Are you testing on a larger dataset ?

Comment: @LdM  Is it possible that in your full set of data, multiple  `Object` can have the same `Field` value ?

Comment: yes, it is possible. I have just checked the full set of data and I found multiple objects having the same field value. Would it be possible to handle with this?

Comment: @LdM  I'm trying to find a way to handle this.

Comment: @LdM  See my edit above.  Added a line `mapping = mapping.groupby(level=0).first()` to aggregate the duplicate entries and get the first one for mapping.  You can try it.

Comment: @LdM  Pleased to help!   Happy programming!  :-)